# How to extend container when it has absolutely positioned elements in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Lets say I have

CSS:

```
.mainWrap { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
.wrap-boxes { positon: relative; }
.box { position:absolute (position and height is generated by plugin isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class"mainWrap">
    <div class="wrap-boxes">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

clearfix applied to wrap-boxes won't work as it has elements with absolute position in it.

therefore i'd need to use jQuery to calculate the height of the boxes in order to extend wrap-box. I don't know the height of these boxes as they have random height and I do not know the total number of boxes as they are constantly generated by the client. I'd need a general jQuery that solves that. If i don't extend the mainWrap the boxes will be cut off and i need to use overflow: hidden for other reasons.

Any help on this?

Comment: i don't see wrap-box in your html, there's wrap-boxes, not sure if that's what you meant. also, the above code is kinda incorrect as it puts all boxes on top of each other. also, i think you don't need jQuery for that, can be done with CSS.

Comment: sorry i update the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
$.fn.wrapHeight = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var height = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function() {
            height += $(this).height();
        }).end().height(height);
    });
};

$('.wrap-boxes').wrapHeight();
```

Comment: thanks. if i apply a border around .wrap-boxes i can only see 1 px top, which tells me its height hasn't changed using that

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a zero as default value before incrementing. Try again.

Comment: i like your .end().height() chain in the end :)

Comment: Appreciate this is a very old question. But you shouldn't need to do this anymore. You can now just re-init masonry to auto-calculate the wrapper container height of your grid. See: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layoutitems

Run this just after your items have finished changing size.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. You need to use JavaScript to  measure the size and position of the child elements and set the size of the parent element accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In pure `JavaScript` you could use the following:

```
var wrapbox = document.getElementById('mainWrap').childNodes[1],
    els = wrapbox.childNodes,
    i,
    height = 0;

for (i in els) {
    if(els[i].nodeType == 1) {
        height += parseInt(els[i].offsetHeight);
    }

    wrapbox.style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AJLe7/1/

Notice I changed the `class="mainWrap"` to `id="mainWrap"` to simplify the answer...

Comment: thanks man, trying to get my head around jQuery at the moment, pure js is a bit too much for my current skills i must admit :)